# Workfront/Attask: Task Automation Off a Custom Form

Tags: attask, workfront-api

In workfront, my team and I are looking for a way to automate task creation off a custom form.

If task creation was automated, we could have custom form fields fill into our calendar.

Is this possible? Any advice would greatly be appreciated.

I'm an amateur coder :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is very possible and something that I've implemented multiple times for my organization.

You'll need to use the API, of course, since none of this is built in to Workfront. However, You don't need too much coding knowledge. Most of our automation is done from powersehll scripts but there are some C# and Java tools in use in my environment too.

To do what you're planning, you'll set up a project as a request queue and attach your custom form(s) to relevant queue topics. Some requests may have approvals (changing statuses) and others may not, depending on your use case.

Then your automation will look something like this:

```
Get all $ISSUES in %PROJECT with %QUEUE_TOPIC whose status is %STATUS
For each %ISSUE in %ISSUES
{
 Create %TASK in %DESTINATION with %ATTRIBUTES (name, owner, description, duration, etc.)
 Set %ISSUE to %STATUS_DONE
}
```

Obviously there's a lot of customization that can be done, but you can come up with some great automation using the API. We have user provisioning, new project registration, form modifications, template updates, etc. all done through automation.